# Where is my private key?

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

I was following [this](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/copy-id) tutorial to generate and assign a key to one of my servers, but before running `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/mykey user@host` I was tring to find my private key and guess what I can't find it. :x

Sorry if this is recurring question but I've check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/512935/where-are-stored-ssh-client-private-keys) before but I can't get any answer to my question.

---

So, I've run `ssh-keygen` then tried `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa/mykeyname`but there's no key.
Also `ls ~/.ssh -a` only shows the `known_hosts` file.

But I can see the public key in my home folder. `mykey.pub`

I'm kinda new to the ssh authentication process so I would love some help or if the case some link to another question ( I'll delete this question if needed).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `So, I've run ssh-keygen then tried cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa/mykeynamebut there's no key.`

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean, and I know my English is not perfect. But, did you read my question?

Comment: I did, and I understand how it works.  The file name is `~/.ssh/id_rsa` by default.  If you typed in the name of `mykey` then you will have both a `mykey` which should be the private key and `mykey.pub` being the public in your `~/.ssh` folder.  If both files are not there, you did not follow the directions properly.

Comment: `id_rsa` is supposed to be a file, not a directory. There can't be a `~/.ssh/id_rsa/mykeyname`.

Comment: Okidoki, sorry for the "anger". Some people ask things for yesterday to unexperience people. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Might I add a little note here.  Those instructions can make it more difficult to use the private / public keys by making you have to type in the name of the key you have used every time you want to connect to the other host without a password.  If you go with only the default settings, ssh will default to the key of `id_rsa` and there is no need to specify it every time you want to connect.

Comment: So how do you connect then? `ssh -i user@host` it's enough? It will fetch the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key? I'm adding the keys because I need create some scripts to migrate data.

Comment: Mine is just `ssh user@host` after I have ran the `ssh-copy-id user@host` command without specifying a new key.  Using the `-i` requires a name and if you have a lot of different ones then you will have to remember them all.  Just a thought.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll need to dive in ssh docs to get more useful info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you followed that tutorial *exactly* i.e. answered `mykey` at the prompt

```
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/ylo/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

then it will be in a file called `mykey` in your current directory.

If you want it to be in the default location `~/.ssh/id_rsa` then simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> at that prompt to accept the default value.

Comment: Thanks my friend, yup that was my problem. I' ve create on my home dir, but since i've so many `trash`i didn't notice the private since it has no extension.